# How to override a specific workspace app's peer dependency with pnpm

Tags: pnpm

In our project we are using `pnpm` alongside `npm workspaces`.

The issue is that we would like to override a dependency of a devDependency in a single application. With npm we could write this in the app's `package.json` using the `"overrides"` attribute.

It does not seem like pnpm uses npm's `"overrides"` attribute at all, but would rather use `"pnpm.overrides"` attribute in the root package.json. This is fine, except that I would like to override a single app's dependency and not all apps that use that dependency, which is what `pnpm.overrides` seem to do.

Tried using `npm overrides` to override a single package's dependency. Uninstalling it and then installing it again did not change anything. I would expect pnpm to honor it, but later found out it did not.